# I changed toolbar hamburger icon but it does not open drawer menu when I clicked

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar, slidingdrawer

I am using android toolbar instead of action bar as you can see below inside code. I changed hamburger icon with what my clients want. But drawer menu does not open when I clicked on icon. Here is my code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_event_list);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.icon_menu);
    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(menuClicked);
    toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));

    mRecyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mAdapter=new MenuAdapter(titles,icons,u.fullName,u.email,R.drawable.a,this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    Drawer=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);
    mDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,Drawer,toolbar,R.string.app_name,R.string.app_name){
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            // code here will execute once the drawer is opened( As I dont want anything happened whe drawer is
            // open I am not going to put anything here)
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            // Code here will execute once drawer is closed
        }
    };
    mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.icon_menu);
    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
    Drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

and xml for this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#syncState()):

> `syncState()` should be called from your Activity's `onPostCreate` method to synchronize after the DrawerLayout's instance state has been restored, and any other time when the state may have diverged.

Consider moving your call to `syncState()` to `onPostCreate` after the state has settled.

Comment: I updated the code. It was already in onCreate. I am looking for onPostCreate

Comment: It gives nullPointerException when i do it inside onPostCreate here is a little bit of errors                                                                                     05-13 19:35:21.141  22946-22946/com.mobigo.apps.mobiticket E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mobigo.apps.mobiticket, PID: 22946
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:1764)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:883)

Comment: I solved the error but it still does not open the navigation drawer when i cliked the changed icon

Answer (score 0):

Missing some Overrides in the Activity

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
    // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
      return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```